# Menu cuts off in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

My site: https://rvreviews.net/
has the menu cut off. I have tried
display: flex
but it lists the items one at a time. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it on the wrong element. For the record, on theGem theme by Codex, you need to add this:
#primary-menu.no-responsive
{white-space:normal}